# Deploying only the generated code, without the composer.json file, and with "vendor" inside the "src" directory

Tags: php, deployment, composer-php

I have a project with all the `composer.json`, `phpunit.xml`, etc in the project's root directory.

All the `.php` sources are in `src/`

I have configured composer.json as follows:

```
{
  "name" : "myproj",
  "config" : {
    "vendor-dir" : "src/vendor"
  },
  "autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
      "myclasses\\" : "src/classes"
    }
  }
}
```

This works beautifully on my dev machine.

The issue is that I only want to deploy the contents of the `src` directory so that I do not get all the project metadata on the deployment server.

Unfortunately the autoloader looks for the classes in `/var/www/test/vendor/composer/../../../src/classes/` instead of e.g. `/var/www/test/vendor/composer/../../classes/`

> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/test/vendor/composer/../../../src/classes/myclasses/core/messages/MessageList.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/test/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Is there a clever configuration I can make? Or am I forced to move `composer.json` (which I see as meta-data not needed for production) into `/src`?

Comment: if its `/var/www/test/src/classes` you wouldn't want `/var/www/test/classes`

Comment: Not really. Everything in `src` is in `/var/www/test` I want the autoloader to skip the `/../src` part

Comment: _"I want the autoloader to skip the /../src part"_ - So change it in your composer.json file? You can point your namespace "myclasses" to where ever you want. What "project metadata" is it you don't want on the deployment server? The composer.json file? How are you deploying the application? Can't you just setup your deployment script to handle what is being deployed?

Comment: it dont work like that ,you would need to change composer.json and remove the `src/` then run `composer du`, but obviously it then won't work locally when you have src

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I run `composer install` and `composer -o dumpautoloader` on my jenkins server and then scp it to the target server, which does not have composer, etc. ofc I could always keep `composer.json` in the deployment dir and then delete it so it's not on the destination server

Comment: Are you `scp` ing the `src` directory, or the _contents_ of `src` directory? As in, is there a `/var/www/test/src` on the server?

Comment: @yivi in `src` the pipeline executes something akin to `scp * destinationserver:/var/www/test/` the folder `src` does not exist on `destinationserver` I essentially would like to have the `classes` folder structure relative to the `vendor` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The composer.json file it's never used at runtime. There is no use for it anyway, it's only used by the composer command. If you do not run  `composer` in your production machine, you do not need to ever upload it.

Your project it's not failing because "you are not deploying composer.json" with the code, but because you are dumping the autoloader having certain structure, which you actually mention in your `composer.json` configuration, and then trying to run the server with a *different* directory structure.

When you run `composer install` and `composer dumpautoloader` your project looks like this:

```
composer.json
src/ <--- this is where autoloader looks for your files.
--- yourCode/
--- moreCode/
--- vendor/
------ autoloader.php
```

But then in your server you on your server you have

```
yourCode/
moreCode/
vendor/
--- autoload.php <--- this can't find the 'src' directory
```

The solution is not to upload the **contents** of your `src` directory, but the `src` directory itself.

Any other script that needs to use the autoloader and the rest of the code should just include `/var/www/test/src/vendor/autoload.php` and everything would work as it should.

If you do not want to have a `src` directory inside `test`, then you shouldn't have it during the autoloader generation. Do not make your development and staging environments different from your production environment.

Your only alternative would be to do in your build machine:

- run `composer install`
- move `composer.json` to `src`
- change `composer.json` so the paths declared on the `autoload` key do not mention `src`
- run `composer dumpautoload`
- delete `composer.json`
- upload `src` contents.

It's not guaranteed to work and it's a brittle solution, but the problem is that you are trying to use the tool in a way that runs counter to the design of the tool.

Comment: I Like your answer, but cannot use it. I am bound to use it on a host (in prod) where I cannot modify the path, and therefore have to deploy to a certain folder. I like the symmetry of the meta files (like the Jenkinsfile, phpunit.xml, phpmd, .git folder, .gitignore), and test classes not being deployed in production. Based on the comments, I will move the `composer.json` into the `src` folder and just delete it from the deployment server.

Comment: But you cannot do it any other way. The structure on the server needs to match the directory structure from whenever you generate the autoloader. Or you would need to have a different composer.json file in development (your machine), and the build machine. And that looks like looking for problems.

Comment: I had just hoped that since i could define the path of the `vendor` folder, I could have more control of how it worked.

Comment: The problem is that when you run `composer dumpautoload` you have one configuration, and then you want to use the generated autoload in a setting that does not match that configuration. If you think about it, you'll realize it's a problematic proposition.